# Print html in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, cordova

I use this code to get Json data and print it dependent on the same id but
it's print once and doesn't print all data.

```
var neededData0; 
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1/appcpanel/appapi/civil_khams', 
function(jsonData) {

neededData0 = jsonData; 

for(var i = 0; i < neededData0.length; i++)
{

  var id = neededData0[i]['id_kh'];
  var name = neededData0[i]['title'];

if(id == 13){
  $(".dyList").text(name);
  $(".dyList").text(name);
  $(".dyList").text(name);
}

if(id == 8){
  $(".dyList").text(name);
  $(".dyList").text(name);
  $(".dyList").text(name);
}

}
```

Comment: Because you are clearing all past data on every next loop. You should have to use `append` instead of `text`, and single element for every if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
var neededData0; 
$.getJSON('http://admin:123@127.0.0.1/appcpanel/appapi/civil_khams', 
function(jsonData) {
neededData0 = jsonData; 
for(var i = 0; i < neededData0.length; i++)
{
    var id = neededData0[i]['id_kh'];
    var name = neededData0[i]['title'];

    if(id == 13){
        $(".dyList").append(name+'<br>');
    }
    if(id == 8){
        $(".dyList").append(name+'<br>');
    }
}
```